# Create nested JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

Im trying to create a Json object with the outcome below.
Im not able to get my head around how it should be done with all the nesting. Can anyone help me out?

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            12.82114,
            56.6762238
          ],
          [
            12.8211,
            56.67633
          ],
          [
            12.82085,
            56.67668
          ],
          [
            12.82106,
            56.6767
          ],
          [
            12.82135,
            56.67675
          ],
          [
            12.82164,
            56.67683
          ],
          [
            12.82188,
            56.67693
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "blue"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? `{` means an object and `[` is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```cs
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string stroke { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class FeatureCollection
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}
```